# Vue component will not render in ASP.NET Core MVC view using the component's selector

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, vuejs3, .net-6.0, primevue

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app. I don't want to completely re-write the views but would like to use Vue in order to partially update some of the list/dropdown controls with PrimeVue controls.

I have a Vue project with `*.vue` and `*.ts` files living outside of the `wwwroot` of my ASP.NET Core MVC application. I've used the `npm run build` command successfully and have the Vue application's `*.js` file output to `~/VueJs/dist/[app-name].js` in my application's web root.

My problem is that custom component selectors will not render when used inside the Vue app `<div>`.

I have a contractors vue component, like so:

```vue
<template>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-baseline">
        <input :name="props.inputName" :id="props.inputId" type="hidden" :value="selectedValue" />
        <label>Contractor</label>
        <Dropdown v-model="selectedValue" :options="selectOptions" filter optionLabel="ContractorName" optionValue="Id"
            filterMatchMode="startsWith" placeholder="Select a Contractor" class="w-full md:w-14rem ml-2">
        </Dropdown>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

import Dropdown from 'primevue/dropdown';

    const props = defineProps({
        inputId: String,
        inputName: String,
    })
    
    const selectedValue = ref()

    const selectOptions = ref()

    const getContractors = () => {
        axios.get("/odata/Contractors?$select=Id,ContractorName&$orderby=ContractorName")
             .then((result: any) => {
                selectOptions.value = result.data
             })
    }

    onMounted(() => {
        getContractors()
    })

</script>
```

Here's my `App.vue` code:

```vue
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import ContractorList from './components/lookup-lists/ContractorList.vue'

</script>
```

This is my `main.ts` code:

```vue
import './assets/main.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';

import App from './App.vue'
import ContractorList from './components/lookup-lists/ContractorList.vue'

const app2 = createApp(App)
app2.use(createPinia())
app2.use(PrimeVue)
app2.component('ContractorList', ContractorList)
app2.mount('#app2')
```

I also tried:

```vue
const app2 = createApp({}) // <- {} instead of App
app2.use(createPinia())
app2.use(PrimeVue)
app2.component('ContractorList', ContractorList)
app2.mount('#app2')
```

When I do the following in the ASP.NET Core MVC view, nothing is rendered; I made sure that the vue version matches the project's version stated in `package.json`

```
"vue": "^3.3.10"
```

```razor
<div class="row mb-2">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div id="app2">
            <ContractorList/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.3.10/vue.global.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/VueJs/dist/[app-name].js"></script>
```

However, if I use the `ContractorList` as my Vue application's root component, instead of the `App` component or `{}`, it renders just fine:

```vue
const app2 = createApp(ContractorList)
app2.use(createPinia())
app2.use(PrimeVue)
app2.mount('#app2')
```

I'm stumped at this point and I'm not sure how to expose the `ContractorList` (or any additional component) in the Vue `app2` object, so that `<ContractorList/>` will work in `<div id="app2"></div>`.

Thanks